# Converting HTML to Plain Text for MapKit Annotations

Tags: iphone, ios, string, annotations, mapkit

I have a problem when I use an annotation to see information with MapKit.

Comment: stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText is an extension youve added to string right? You should post that since thats where the error occurs, no one will able to help you otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue.  You're not crazy.  I believe it's a bug in the MapKit code.  The Annotation object doesn't create it's own copy of the strings you pass to it. When your string goes out of scope, the map makes a bad reference. Try re-allocating the strings before you pass them.  Like so:

```
NSString *tempT = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:itemT];
NSString *tempA = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:itemA];
addAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:essai :tempT :tempA];
```

And then don't release them until you're finished displaying the map.

Comment: See Rickay's answer, he found the root issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem, as Jonesy mentioned, but there **is** a fix. I'm not sure what kind of class you have for your annotations, but I use this:

Annotation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LocationAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString* title;
    NSString* subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) MKPinAnnotationColor pinColor;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* subtitle;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c
                    title:(NSString*) t
                 subtitle:(NSString*) st;

- (void)moveAnnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) newCoordinate;

- (NSString*)subtitle;

- (NSString*)title;

@end
```

And Annotation.m:

```
#import "LocationAnnotation.h"

@implementation LocationAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, pinColor, title, subtitle;

- (NSString *)subtitle {
return subtitle;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return title;
}

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) c
                  title:(NSString*)t 
               subtitle:(NSString*)st
{
    coordinate = c;
    self.title = t;
    self.subtitle = st;
    return self;
}

- (void)moveAnnotation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)newCoordinate
{
    coordinate = newCoordinate;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

To implement it:

```
Annotation* ann = [[[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:startLocation title:someStringAutoreleasedOrNot subtitle:someOtherStringAutoreleasedOrNot] autorelease];
[yourMapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

Really, the key here is that in the annotation class, the title and subtitle properties are declared as type copy. This makes a new copy of the string you assign it, so it can be released without causing the crash that you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see stringByStandardizingWhitespace method call in the above code you pasted... It would be helpful if you can post the code which has the error. Use debugger to know where the error is occuring...

Also one error which is not related to the syntax/error you specified but would effect the logic later:

you are assigning the gps_long tag tpo lat and vice versa ...